# Infinity and nan in jQuery function

Tags: jquery

Here is my jQuery function I get **infinity** and **nan** in the results.

I am calling this in an **Onblur** event, I do not know where my mistake in this function is.

This is the first time I am facing **infinity** with a jQuery function.

I do not know where I made a mistake in my function.

[image]

```
function gettotal()
{
  var item_id       = $('.item_id').val() != '' ? $('.item_id').val() : 0;
  var kg            = $('.kg').val() != '' ? $('.kg').val() : 0;
  var touch         = $('.touch').val() != '' ? $('.touch').val() : 0;
  var total         = $('.total').val() != '' ? $('.total').val() : 0;
  var minius        = $('.minius').val() != '' ? $('.minius').val() : 0;
  var total         = $('.total').val() != '' ? $('.total').val() : 0;
  var kediamPer     = $('.kediamPer').val() != '' ? $('.kediamPer').val() : 0;
  var kediam        = $('.kediam').val() != '' ? $('.kediam').val() : 0;
  var jasatper      = $('.jasatper').val() != '' ? $('.jasatper').val() : 0;
  var jasatwt       = $('.jasatwt').val() != '' ? $('.jasatwt').val() : 0;
  var copper        = $('.copper').val() != '' ? $('.copper').val() : 0;
  var totalWet      = 0;
  var gross         = 0;
  var grossKdm      = 0;
  var grosscop      = 0;
  var grossjasat    = 0;

  totalWet = (parseFloat(kg) * (parseFloat(100) / parseFloat(touch)));
  $('.total').val(totalWet.toFixed(0));

  gross = (parseFloat(total) - (parseFloat(kg)));
  $('.minius').val(gross.toFixed(0));

  gross = (parseFloat(total) - (parseFloat(kg)));
  $('.minius').val(gross.toFixed(0));

  if(item_id == 1)
  {
      grossKdm = (parseFloat(minius) * (parseFloat(kediamPer)) / 100);
      $('.kediam').val(grossKdm.toFixed(0));

      grosscop = (parseFloat(minius) - (parseFloat(kediam)));
      $('.copper').val(grosscop.toFixed(0));
  }
  else
  {
      grossjasat = (parseFloat(minius) * (parseFloat(jasatper)) / 100);
      $('.jasatwt').val(grossjasat.toFixed(0));

      grosscop = (parseFloat(minius) - (parseFloat(jasatwt)));
      $('.copper').val(grosscop.toFixed(0));
  }
}
```

Comment: try doing parseFloat() of the input directly. If the value of input is " " or something else but not number it will be NaN otherwise you will get the decimal value.

Comment: @Rajan471 what should i have to do change in  my jquery function can you tell me?

Comment: console.log() is your friend, see what is failing....

Answer (score 0):

I think there is writing infinity because the default value of "Touch" is 0. You are doing a division and you can t divide something with 0.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
program substituire_MA_cu_TA;
var s:string; 
i:integer;begin writeln('Dati sirul'); readln(s); i:=2; 
while i<=length(s) do if s[i-1]+s[i]='MA' then s[i-1]:='T' 
else i:=i+1; 
writeln('sirul obtinut este=',s); readln
end.
```